# AngularJS component template namespace SVG

Tags: javascript, angularjs, svg

Since AngularJS 1.5, we are now able to create components, using the component() method of angular module. But, it seems not possible to create a component for a SVG template...

With directive(), I was able to use :

```
.directive('svgInternal', function () {
  return {
    templateNamespace: 'svg',
    template: '<g><rect height="25" width="25" /></g>',
  };
})
```

But with component(), templateNamespace definition is not possible anymore...

In Angular >=2, I know it is possible to define the namespace prefix in the element tag for components (of course, not working with AngularJS component()):

```
template: `<svg:g><rect height="25" width="25" /></svg:g>`
```

**Does anyone know if there is a way to use AngularJS component() with SVG template?**

From AngularJS 1.5 components documentation:

> When not to use Components: (...)
>       when you need advanced directive definition options like priority, terminal, multi-element

Comment: I would like to know this as well.